# Toolbar scrolled off screen on form

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

The new Android Toolbar gives us some flexibility in what we can do with the actionbar, but I have ran into an issue.  I'm using a ToolBar in the layout of my activity as an actionbar('AppBar' is correct name now I guess).  When user focuses on a edittext the content is scrolled up by the system to let the user see the field.  It also scrolls the ToolBar up and off the screen.  This is a problem because navigation is on the Toolbar and now hidden from the user.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <Toolbar
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize">
   </Toolbar>
</LinearLayout>
```

How can we keep the ToolBar in place?

Comment: wait do you have the toolbar in a scrollview or something? the toolbar does not inherently scroll when you do

Comment: This is the layout above, minus the EditTexts, images, etc.  There is not a scrollview.  Using android:Theme.Material.NoActionbar as parent theme.  Also noticed that the statusbar color scrolls up as well.

Comment: @tyczj It does scroll on my Nexus 5 with latest 5.0 image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by placing a ScrollView below the Toolbar and putting content in it.  Also will need to set android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" on the activity.  Also, to avoid the actionmode pushing the toolbar down, add this attribute

```
android:windowActionModeOverlay="true"
```

Comment: This doesn't help if your Toolbar is transparent with content (say ImageView) intentionally showing underneath.